# Human Movement Data

Tags: data-request, travel

I'm interested in studying human movement (any type of transportation except aerial), specifically related to health.

I would assume most of this data is owned by one possible creators/collectors of it, such as telecom companies (which record their cellphone client's position on the cell "handover" procedure).

I've searched around the web and have not found data sources yet.

Do any other open data sources, in which I could obtain at the very least *trends* of human movement, exist? For now I'm not interested in international migration. Any country is OK.

What I'm interested in is the "movement" people usually do, their commutes, and their most usual movements. I'd use this data to research it jointly with case data (of multiple different diseases) and see if there's a correlation.

Comment: Hi @JanDoggen, thanks for your reply. I will edit to answer your questions.  And I did mean multinational, what I'm trying to convey is that I'm interested in data within nations, but not from nation to nation (not international).

Answer (score 1):

US Census has [Commuting (Journey to Work) Main](https://www.census.gov/hhes/commuting/) datasets, though they aren't specifically related to health.
Census has other commuting datasets as well, but if I recall correctly, they are in the same vein as not being specifically health related.